# Is there any Kafka client library that can run on browser?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, apache-kafka

I have written an Angular 4 project (using Typescript and  Angular-cli).
From which, I need to produce messages to a kakfa broker hosted in some other machine using some JavaScript/Typescript Kafka client library.

kafka-node, no-kafka, and few other packages that I tried to use in angular web application didn't run on browser.

Comment: Likely not. I'd suggest setting up a simple REST API or Websocket server that you can hook into from your Angular application.

Comment: Thanks @djfdev. May i know what is that stopping to communicate to kafka from browser? When it's easily possible from nodejs and not browser

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Kafka REST Proxy from Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html). If you can make REST calls, you can produce & consume from Kafka.

Comment: Thanks @Robin. May i know why there is no client library to connect to kafka from browser. When there are enough libs for nodejs.

What is that stopping to communicate to kafka from browser?

Comment: As I said, you can use any RESTful-capable client library of your choosing and the Kafka REST proxy to do what you want.